# My login form cant echo "your password is incorrect" but can only login

Tags: php

So i have written this code for my login page, but the problem is that its only able to login and not able to tell the user that the username or password was incorrect. Some help would be nice

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'dbh.php';

$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid='$uid' AND pwd='$pwd'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "your username or password is incorrect!";
} else {
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];

}

header("Location: index.php");
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: You haven't described what 'not able to' means, what actually happens, etc. Additionally, this code is wildly insecure - use prepared statements and don't store passwords in plaintext.

Answer (score 1):

Your if condition should be like this:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)
if (!$row) {
    echo "your username or password is incorrect!";
} else {
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
}
```

Also, the way you are doing is complete unsafe, and is vulnerable to SQL injection, it is better to use prepared statements

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide much background. It would be essential to know index.php at least.

But I guess, the problem you face is that the script redirects to index.php independently from the outcome of the if-else before. So, you will always see login-behavior. You should **move the header("Location: index.php"); into the else-branch** after the $_SESSION statement.

Also, be sure that the session is deleted in some logout during your testing.

**Remark to the other answers:**
(I cannot comment yet, so I put the comment here.) The other answers tell you not to use

```
if( ! $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) { ... } else { ... }
```

I agree that it is not a nice way of programming. But PHP actually allows it. $row will get the contents of mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ). And additionally the if statement will be executed if that content evaluates to false. It's nicer to use

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if( ! $row ) { ... } else { ... }
```

But I do not think that will solve your problem.

**Additional remark:**
The comments are right that your code should only be used for practicing not for real-world web applications. It allows SQL injection because $uid and $pwd are not escaped. And the password is stored in plaintext in your database. No reasonable user of a normal web page would tolerate that.

Comment: Thanks, might not be a secret but im really really new to programming and just practicing, i am not intending to acutally use it, but would still be nice to learn where the mistake is. What other information would be needed to fix the problem?

Comment: And by moving the header("Location: index.php"); into the else branch worked, thank you very much

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, I think you can accept it. (I am new to Stackoverflow as you are to programming. :-) ) For answering it would have been helpful to know what index.php does exactly, in particular if it checks the content of $_SESSION['id'] thereby checking the login status or if it is just the page after the login. I think it is the latter option. Of course, for a real web application that does not make much sense, either. If a user knows the URL, he could go to index.php directly without logging in. So, normally, you would check the log-in status for every requested page.

Answer (score 0):

`=` is not a valid comparison operator in php. You must use `==` or `===`.

In this case you also want to find if the two values are equal, and simply adding a `!` before `$row` will not work. You should use

```
if ($row !== mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

instead.

Furthermore, your code is **very** vulnerable and your database can be broken into within minutes and all passwords obtained if you choose to simply leave it like this. You should look into [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) (to prevent SQL injections which can access your database without proper authentication by abusing your input fields) and you should also **never leave your passwords stored in plaintext**. They should always be hashed, and even better, salted.